# Customize Release Page

Tags: goreleaser

Context, prior to tagging a release, the team prepares a `RELEASE_NOTES.md` file. We would like to use the contents of this file as the contents to display on the release page after we cut the release.

Is it possible to customize the contents of a release page on Github by simply using the contents of an existing file?

I see that you can customize it via existing files goreleaser provides as documented in https://goreleaser.com/customization/release/#github. Is it possible to maybe `cat` a file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There are a couple of flags in the `goreleaser release` command:

```
  --release-footer string        Load custom release notes footer from a markdown file
  --release-footer-tmpl string   Load custom release notes footer from a templated markdown file (overrides --release-footer)
  --release-header string        Load custom release notes header from a markdown file
  --release-header-tmpl string   Load custom release notes header from a templated markdown file (overrides --release-header)
  --release-notes string         Load custom release notes from a markdown file
  --release-notes-tmpl string    Load custom release notes from a templated markdown file (overrides --release-notes)
```

You probably want `--release-notes`.